# WordPress table wp_options has been hacked

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Today one of my WordPress websites has been hacked.

After one hour searching for changes in the WordPress code and not having found any change, I have found out that the table wp_options has been updated by the hacker.

The values “siteurl” and “home” have been updated in the column “option_name” so that all visitors of my website were redirected to the hacker websites.

To solve this issue, I have revoked the “Update” privilege from the current database user so that he won’t be allowed to update the table anymore.

I'm afraid that this solution will cause problems when upgrading plugins or WP core as I think some upgrade will need to update values in the table wp_options such as version number or other values.

Is there anybody who knows a better solution? Or do you think this is the best solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from the WP community, they found my solution wrong but acceptable as a temporary solution. As the hack occurred after I have upgraded to the latest version 5.1.1 I must conclude this is a leek of this new version. I posted a message on the WP community and I hope they will fix it asap. I would appreciate meanwhile to hear from other people having the same issue. Thank you